# Bash seq to produce two separate sequences of numbers in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, seq

I would like to create a simple for bash loop that iterates over a sequence of numbers with a specific interval and then a different sequence of numbers, e.g.

```sh
for i in $(seq 0 5 15)
do
    echo $i
done
```

But after interating through `i`=0, 5, 10, 15, I'd like it to iterate through say 30, 35, 40, 45 as well.

Is there a way to do this using `seq`? Or an alternative?

Comment: The actual content of the for loop is more than just echo$i (about 200 lines) I don't want to repeat it and make my script huge!

Comment: You can put those 200 lines in a function and call it twice.

Comment: Just `seq 0 5 45` and check that it's not 20 or 25 at the top and `continue` if it is?

Comment: @Kevin I think your suggestion works for this example, but not in the general case (e.g. if the interval changes).

Comment: Note that `seq` should rarely, if ever, be used in a shell script. Most modern shells have more efficient alternatives (such as C-style for loops), and a script that requires POSIX compatibility cannot use `seq` because it is not defined by POSIX. (You would use a `while` loop and update the index yourself instead.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Approach 1

Simply augment the command within `$(...)` with another call to `seq`:

```sh
for i in $(seq 0 5 15; seq 30 5 45); do
    echo $i
done
```

and then

```
$ bash test.sh
0
5
10
15
30
35
40
45
```

## # Approach 2

In your follow-up comment, you write

> The actual content of the for loop is more than just `echo$i` (about 200 lines) I don't want to repeat it and make my script huge!

As an alternative to the approach outlined above, you could define a shell function for those 200 lines and then call the function in a series of `for` loops:

```sh
f() {
   # 200 lines
   echo $i
}

for i in $(seq 0 5 15) do
    f
done

for i in $(seq 30 5 45) do
    f
done
```

## Approach 3 (POSIX-compliant)

For maximum portability across shells, you should make your script POSIX-compliant. In that case, you need have to eschew `seq`, because, although many distributions provide that utility, it's not defined by POSIX.

Since you can't use `seq` to generate the sequence of integers to iterate over, and because POSIX doesn't define numeric, C-style `for` loops, you have to resort to a `while` loop instead. To avoid duplicating the code related to that loop, you can define another function (called `custom_for_loop` below):

```sh
custom_for_loop () {
  # $1: initial value
  # $2: increment
  # $3: upper bound
  # $4: name of a function that takes one parameter
  local i=$1
  while [ $i -le $3 ]; do
      $4 $i
      i=$((i+$2))
  done
}

f () {
    printf "%s\n" "$1"
}

custom_for_loop 0 5 15 f
custom_for_loop 30 5 45 f
```

Comment: Also, `for i in $(seq 0 5 15) $(seq 30 5 45)` will work.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to define a new command to wrap the loop, but the loop structure itself looks fine.

Comment: @chepner Well, I agree that wrapping the loop in a function is overkill, here. However, if there were many similar loops to go through, it would make sense to abstract the loop away.